# Unable to connect to mongo server

Tags: mongodb

[image]Im using mongoDb V 3.4 and trying to start the server but it says

```
C:\Users\gokul ram>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-11-18T09:25:27.061+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-11-18T09:25:27.062+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I also tried with --dbpath command, but it is waiting for connection for long time, still not getting connected

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod --dbpath "C:/data/db"
2017-11-18T09:36:03.368+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting :     pid=4660 port=27017 dbpath=C:/data/db 64-bit host=GOK_RAM
2017-11-18T09:36:03.370+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-11-18T09:36:03.370+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-11-18T09:36:03.371+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-11-18T09:36:03.372+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-11-18T09:36:03.372+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "C:/data/db" } }
2017-11-18T09:36:03.375+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:/data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-11-18T09:36:03.376+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1509M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-11-18T09:36:04.096+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-11-18T09:36:04.097+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-11-18T09:36:04.097+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-11-18T09:36:04.098+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-11-18T09:36:04.098+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files.
2017-11-18T09:36:04.098+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-11-18T09:36:05.880+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-11-18T09:36:05.882+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Is that problem with the mongo db version or my configurations? Any faced the same issue please help me!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: navigate to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\` and run **mongod.exe** this will start the server .

**second** : in a new cmd typein **mongo**
 this might work

Comment: The first step got connection failed 

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-11-18T10:24:44.712+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-11-18T10:24:44.712+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: check the path whether it's correct manually by looking at the folder structure

Comment: can you give me a screenshot of your cmd with the error

Comment: added screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to start the mongo server using 'mongod.exe' command and set 'data\db' as dbpath where the data will be stored. Make sure the folders are created before running the command.
adding C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\ to your environment variable 'PATH' will be beneficial.
To run the server type the following command in cmd prompt:
mongod --dbpath = C:\data\db
The server should run with default settings at port 27017

To connect to the server, open another cmd prompt and execute the 'mongo.exe' command. This should work.
Else you can try specifying the port number "mongo --port 27017"

Comment: I have did the same. But still facing the same problem. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of "mongod.exe" command also?
You can also try to install mongod as a windows service, that will require you to create a mongod.conf file and install

Answer (score 0):

**First**
We Need to Start the mongo server with --dbpath command

**Next** open seperate command window, 
Set path to mongo bin and use mongo.exe command

Then you can start accesing mongo server.